# ASP.NET core app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute not called on 401 initial error

Tags: asp.net-core, error-handling

I have configured error handling in my ASP.NET Core application:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/api/v1/error/{0}");
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/api/v1/error/{0}");
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/v1/error");

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }

namespace JPSAPI.Controllers
{
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/error")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult ServerError()
    {
        var feature = this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var content = new ExceptionMessageContent()
        {
            Error = "Unexpected Server Error",
            Message = feature?.Error.Message
        };
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), "application/json");
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult StatusCodeError(int statusCode)
    {
        var feature = this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var content = new ExceptionMessageContent();

        content.Error = $"{statusCode}";

        switch (statusCode)
        {
            case 401:
                content.Error = "invalid_token";
                content.Message = "Your login may have timed out, please log in again (401 Unauthorized)";
                break;
            default:
                content.Message = $"Server Error! The Server responded with status code {statusCode}";
                break;
        }
        //{ Error = "Server Error", Message = $"The Server responded with status code {statusCode}" };
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), "application/json");

    }
}
}
```

Neither method is called the first time an error occurs. The methods are called on second and subsequent errors, until session timeout, and then it happens again (assuming session timeout because if I test after coming back from lunch the methods are skipped again on first try). I have placed breakpoints on both methods and neither breakpoint is called on the initial error.

I have tried using app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects which does work on the initial error, but always returns success / 200 to the client which is undesired.

What am I doing wrong that prevents the initial error from being routed like all subsequent errors?

More information:

I am trying to handle exception errors (401, 404, 500 etc). For example, I am using [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) authentication and when testing one of the endpoints with [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), if the token has expired or if it is invalid, a 401 error is returned (in the response header) the first time I hit the Postman send button, the error handler above is not called, and there isn't any JSON payload. If I hit send again in that very same Postman window, the error handler above is called, the JSON payload is returned to the client, and the client gets a 401 error response. It should be doing the latter every time an error is encountered, and never the former.

UPDATE: I guess I did not vet things enough before posting. The above description of events doesn't happen for 404 errors - those exceptions work fine. For the 401 errors, I can either wait for my token to expire, or stop and start the debug session, and it will happen again.

LOGS:

Below is the log information - using IIS Express. I ran Postman for the first time today and tried to access an endpoint twice without a valid token.

I then ran the debugger and tried the endpoint again twice with Postman, closed the debugger, waited a few minutes, and tried with Postman for the final time. Each time, the 401 error was returned, but the JSON payload was returned only with the second attempt.

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-02 17:10:32
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-03-02 17:10:32 ::1 GET /api/v1/userinfo - 49565 - ::1 PostmanRuntime/7.1.1 - 401 0 0 8316
2018-03-02 17:11:02 ::1 GET /api/v1/userinfo - 49565 - ::1 PostmanRuntime/7.1.1 - 401 0 0 522
2018-03-02 17:11:54 ::1 DEBUG / - 49565 - ::1 - - 400 0 64 9598
2018-03-02 17:11:55 ::1 GET /api/values - 49565 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/64.0.3282.167+Safari/537.36 - 400 0 0 6671
2018-03-02 17:11:55 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 49565 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/64.0.3282.167+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:49565/api/values 404 0 0 447
2018-03-02 17:12:07 ::1 GET /api/v1/userinfo - 49565 - ::1 PostmanRuntime/7.1.1 - 401 0 0 448
2018-03-02 17:12:19 ::1 GET /api/v1/userinfo - 49565 - ::1 PostmanRuntime/7.1.1 - 401 0 0 181
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-02 17:37:48
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-03-02 17:37:48 ::1 GET /api/v1/userinfo - 49565 - ::1 PostmanRuntime/7.1.1 - 401 0 0 3533
2018-03-02 17:37:53 ::1 GET /api/v1/userinfo - 49565 - ::1 PostmanRuntime/7.1.1 - 401 0 0 484
```

Comment: What type of errors are you handling? Is the first one a different kind?

Comment: Added more information in post - see the text under 'More Informaiton:'  Thanks  :^)

Comment: That's odd. Can you share the app logs?

Comment: Sorry @Tratcher can you point me to a link that describes how to create the logs you are looking for <embarrassed>?

Comment: Interesting note though, I tested with an endpoint that didn't exist first, got the 404 error with the JSON payload the first time, then tried with an existing endpoint but invalid token - 401 error but no JSON payload, tried again and got both 401 error and JSON payload.  Seems to be an issue only with the '401 unauthorized' error actually.

Comment: @Tratcher - now that I remember how to find / generate the app logs, should I use the debug default setting of 'Warnings' or something more verbose.  The default setting doesn't seem to have a lot of information - see the update to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a known issue: *[Problems using UseExceptionHandler() and UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute() #221](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/221)*. It happens when using APIVersioning.

I used middleware from here to work around the issue: *[Handling errors in an ASP.NET Core Web API](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/handling-errors-in-asp.net-core-web-api)*. Specifically the section on 'Custom Middleware'.